JSON_OBJECT with low performance
I'm creating triggers to collect changes to records in JSON format. I noticed that generating JSON using JSON_OBJECT is making the operation very slow.
Below is the test case:
CREATE TABLE TRIGGER_TEST (ID NUMBER, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50), PRIMARY KEY (ID) )

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_TEST_I AFTER INSERT ON TRIGGER_TEST FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  XMESSAGE   CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('operation' VALUE 'INSERT',
                      'timestamp' VALUE SYSDATE,
                      'table' VALUE 'TRIGGER_TEST',
                      'primary_key' VALUE JSON_ARRAY (JSON_OBJECT ('field' VALUE 'ID', 'type' VALUE 'NUMBER', 'value' VALUE :NEW.ID) ),
                      'data' VALUE JSON_ARRAY (JSON_OBJECT ('field' VALUE 'DESCRIPTION', 'type' VALUE 'VARCHAR2', 'new' VALUE :NEW.DESCRIPTION) ) RETURNING CLOB)
    INTO XMESSAGE
    FROM DUAL;
  -- do something with json
END;

Running this test:
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1 .. 100000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO TRIGGER_TEST
         VALUES (I, 'REC ' || I);
  END LOOP;

  ROLLBACK;
END;

With the trigger disabled, the script runs in 4s. Enabling the trigger increases the execution time to 14s.
Evaluating the profile, it is noted that the call to JSON_OBJECT consumes close to 8.5s.
By making a small modification to the trigger, I have some performance gains.
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_TEST_I
  AFTER INSERT
  ON TRIGGER_TEST
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  XMESSAGE   CLOB;
BEGIN
  XMESSAGE := JSON_OBJECT ('operation' VALUE 'INSERT',
                           'timestamp' VALUE SYSDATE,
                           'table' VALUE 'TRIGGER_TEST',
                           'primary_key' VALUE JSON_ARRAY (JSON_OBJECT ('field' VALUE 'ID', 'type' VALUE 'NUMBER', 'value' VALUE :NEW.ID) ),
                           'data' VALUE JSON_ARRAY (JSON_OBJECT ('field' VALUE 'DESCRIPTION', 'type' VALUE 'VARCHAR2', 'new' VALUE :NEW.DESCRIPTION) ) );
  -- do something with json
END;

With the modified trigger, the profile indicates a JSON_OBJECT execution time of 6.5s. However, I cannot use the "RETURNING CLOB" clause in PL/SQL, only in SQL. With this modification the execution time is also 14s.
The return necessarily needs to be CLOB, as it can exceed 32k in size in large tables.
I created this minimal scenario, but in the real database, with tables with a few dozen fields, the difference between the triggers is much greater.
So I have some questions:

Why does the second trigger execute faster?

Is there any way to use the second form resulting in a CLOB?

What are the alternatives to speed up JSON generation in this scenario?


I'm using Oracle 19.

A performance problem like this given what you're doing is quite expected. LOB processing is very slow, so you should consider rethinking how you want to do your logging. Normally we just write normal relational records for such purposes. LOBs, especially structured ones, really don't belong natively in a relational database and are just there if truly needed in certain scenarios. When we have a choice, they should be avoided. Really any attempt to combine more than one piece of meaningful information into a single field should be avoided as it is CPU intensive and hard to manipulate.

I think the problem is not caused by the CLOB type. In the case of the second trigger, the return type (default) is varchar2. In this case, there would be no manipulation of lobs that justify the (better, but still) low performance.

The 2nd variant is faster because there is no context switch between the PL/SQL engine and the SQL engine. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57445709/how-to-calculate-context-swicthing-for-anonymous-plsql-block

You are still doing complex string manipulation, in addition to the context switch Martin mentions. You really would be far better off simply writing a normal row with separate scalar columns into a table than working with an exotic datatype (not designed with databases in mind) like JSON in a relational database.

I'm trying to collect modified data in each record and send it to an external application using Advanced Queuing. Using JSON seemed like a good idea. Interestingly, assembling XML using XMLELEMENT under the same conditions and in a similar way is faster.

@marciel.deg you can speed this up if you first make a copy of the modified/inserted/deleted record to an audit table and let the AQ process handle the JSON transformation. That would make the realtime transaction fast (at the cost of a slower processing towards your external application).
